# Emacs JavaScript auto-indentation

Tags: javascript, emacs, indentation

I'm looking for a way to turn off automatic indentation in emacs.  I don't want emacs to automatically indent code when I enter special characters like ; or /*

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What mode are you using?

Comment: As of emacs 23, `js.el` is builtin to emacs, and works well.  The automatic indent can be turned off via `js-auto-indent-flag`.

Answer (score 14):

Steve Yegge's js2-mode is great.

From http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/

An improved JavaScript mode for GNU Emacs.

Features:

- variable (adjustable) indentation
- accurate syntax highlighting
- syntax-error highlighting
- strict-mode warning reporting (such as duplicate var declaration)
- smart line-wrapping in comments and strings
- typing helpers (e.g. matching quotes/brackets)
- code-folding (collapse element as {...})
- supports JavaScript 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7 (including E4X)
- customizable colors, or use font-lock defaults
- many customization options

Eventually aims to be competitive with IntelliJ and other best-of-class JavaScript editors.

Note - this mode is for GNU Emacs, version 21 and higher. It does not support XEmacs.

Comment: He can't compete with Aptana which is free.  It comes with a JS parsers which is as good as js2-modes (if not better b/c of intellisence).  His indentation rules are not adjustable, all you can do is set them to tabs, or variable number of spaces.  Which doesn't keep js2-mode from indenting 8 spaces instead of 4, even if you have it set that way. It doesn't handle comma delimited vars or things like this statement $.each(array,function(), next line will indent against the function

Comment: From the docs:
;; Unlike cc-engine based language modes, js2-mode's line-indentation is not
;; customizable.  It is a surprising amount of work to support customizable
;; indentation.  The current compromise is that the tab key lets you cycle among
;; various likely indentation points, similar to the behavior of python-mode.

Comment: Drew, do you have a link to Aptana's emacs mode?

Answer (score 8):

If you're using an old mode based on CC-mode, `C-c C-l` will toggle electricity.

There's a new Javascript mode that ships with Emacs that can be interactively toggled with `M-x electric-indent-mode`

Comment: It is generally true, but the question is about the JavaScript mode, which overrides this.

Comment: @fiddur There used to be modes based on Cc mode, but the Javascript mode that ships with Emacs isn't based on it.  Now you can toggle it with M-x electric-indent-mode

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the new blessed way to achieve this is:

```
M-x electric-indent-mode
```

This command toggles "electric indentation", i.e. auto-indenting whenever certain special characters are hit.

The best thing is that it works accross major modes, not only for `js-mode` (the default javascript major mode in recent version of Emacs).

Answer (score 0):

Set `javascript-auto-indent-flag` to `nil` before loading javascript-mode. You can either add a line to your `.emacs` file or type

```
M-x customize-group RET javascript RET
```

and edit the value there and save. You may need to restart Emacs for this to take effect; at least in the version of `javascript.el` that I have, the flag is only consulted when setting up the keymap.

Comment: Or if using `js2-mode`, set variable `js2-auto-indent-flag` to nil.

Comment: in emacs 23, the  builtin javascript editing mode is `js-mode`, and the flag that governs automatic indentation attempts is `js-auto-indent-flag`.

Answer (score -4):

This will turn off all indenting: <kbd>M-x</kbd> fundamental-mode